# Issue while selecting Date in twwDateTimePicker

Tags: date, delphi, selection, datetimepicker

I have two `TwwDateTimePicker` controls. Based on the selection of the Date in the first picker, the second picker's Date are changed.

If I select today's date in the first picker, the MinDate for the second picker will be today's date+1, and the MaxDate will  be today's date+15.  If I then change the date in the first picker then dates in the second picker are changed accordingly.

Now, I select today's date in the first picker, and today's date+7 in the second picker.  I then go to the first picker and select the same date (today) that I had selected previously.  The second picker's text will still show the previous selected date (todays date+7).

I click on the drop-down, and by default the focus is on the MinDate.  If I try to select the MinDate, it is not selecting the MinDate.  If I click the drop-down a second time, focus is changed to the selected date (todays date+7) and I'm allowed to select any date.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, please edit it and add your code to the question's body.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem in action. Also, you are using a 3rd party component. Do you have the same problem with Delphi's native `TDateTimePicker` component?

Comment: Which Delphi version? For example, I see a slightly different behaviour between Delphi 7 and Delphi XE7.